# Query about the trim() method in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, trim

I asked a question earlier but met harsh criticism, so here I pose it again. Simpler, and rephrased to appeal to those who may have been concerned about the way I asked it before.

BACKGROUND
I am parsing some HTML for information. I have isolated everything in a series of lines but the content I wish to grab and a bunch of spaces after it. To get rid of the spaces, I opted to use trim(), but I have been having trouble. The last few lines of my code are tests:

```
System.out.println("'" + someString + "'\n'" + someString.trim() + "'");
```

The results were:

```
'Sophomore                                          '
'Sophomore                                          '
```

I was worried I might have a problem with the way I was calling trim(), since we all make mistakes from time to time, so I tested it like this:

```
String s = "   hello         ";
System.out.println("'" + s+ "'\n'" + s.trim() + "'");
```

The results were:

```
'  hello     '
'hello'
```

MY QUESTION
What am I doing wrong? What I want is to get 'Sophomore', not 'Sophomore                                          '

I look forward to your excellent answers (thanks in advance!).

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Not my downvote, but the link is needed.

Comment: I suppose it is. But this is a standalone. I'm not trolling or anything. I may eventually post a video of my IDE if this keeps getting downvoted.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `regex` ?

Comment: It's tagged regex because I figured someone might post an answer with a regex solution if trim() is not an option.

Comment: @OlinKirkland that's not a valid reason to tag the question.

Comment: @Alnitak the tag has been removed. Sorry.

Comment: I think the question is ok and +1 for it. They can say whatever they want. :)

Comment: trim() is for removing white spaces.  You are getting different kind of output that is because you are testing in a wrong way.  look at my answer

Comment: @DavorLozic I really appreciate your thumbs up. Got any ideas how to resolve this, though? :L

Comment: Also why is "What's your question?" thumbed up so much. Did people just not read the question...?

Comment: I think you need to take a look at what encoding your string is, which by the way it's impossible to know based on this information only

Comment: @OlinKirkland Maybe they don't understand English? ^^ No, I don't know the answer. I'm the .NET kind of guy but with this title you've got my attention. :)

Comment: String.trim() removes characters less that or equal to space i.e. (char) 32.  As such it doesn't remove all white spaces, but it does remove some control characters which are not white space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.trim()` [specifically only removes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) characters before the first character whose code exceeds `\u0020`, and after the last such character.

This is insufficient to remove *all* possible white space characters - Unicode defines several more (with code points above `\u0020`) that will not be matched by `.trim()`.

Perhaps your white space characters aren't the ones you think they are?

**EDIT** comments revealed that the extra characters were indeed "special" whitespace characters, specifically `\u00a0` which is a Unicode "non-breaking space".  To replace those with normal spaces, use:

```
str = str.replace('\u00a0', ' ');
```

Comment: THANK YOU. THAT MIGHT BE IT. I've been thinking this for a while. What could they be?? If they aren't spaces, why do they look like them??

Comment: Agree. The critical thing he's not showing us is the pre-processed text such as a small test case data that shows the error. 1+

Comment: @OlinKirkland try looping over the string and using `codePointAt` to find out each characters values.  They might be alternate unicode characters, for example.

Comment: @ Hovercraft, what do you mean by the pre-processed text? The exact copy before I cut out the beginning and end of the string?

Comment: @Olin: a small bit of text that when processed by the [sscce](http://sscce.org) that you would normally post for a question like this, would reproduce the problem.

Comment: 53 6f 70 68 6f 6d 6f 72 65 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0 a0

This is the output when I did what muratgu suggested. I think I'm getting a little deep for my expertise. What does this mean, exactly? Do you guys know?

Comment: The `a0` characters are your problem.  They're a Unicode "no-break-space" and as such not recognised by `.trim()`.  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm

Comment: Well, damn. Will I just have to write my own trim() method to take care of just a0 characters? Or better yet, use replace() to replace a0 with " "?

How do I apply replace to the character hexes?

Stupid college sites not using actual spaces.

Comment: @OlinKirkland, [Non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

Comment: @OlinKirkland you should be able to write a regex (oh, the irony...) to replace `\u0040` with an normal space, and then use `.trim` as before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455218/remove-specific-character-from-a-string-based-on-hex-value-c-sharp

Comment: @muratgu that answer is c#, not Java

Comment: @OlinKirkland `str = str.replace('\u0040', ' ');`

Answer (score 1):

There must be a non-whitespace character in the source string. 
Add the following to your code and see what it prints.

```
for (char ch : someString.toCharArray()) {
     System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(ch) + " ");
}
```

Comment: join the conversation on Alnitak's answer. I'm posting subsequent information there.